# What happened between Odin and Loki after Dark World and Ragnarok

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

Has it been explained what transpired betwen Loki and Odin that enabled Loki to assume Odin's form and banish the real Odin to Earth?

> I thought I heard Odin say something along the lines of "it took me some time to realize I was under your spell" in Thor: Ragnarok, but is there a more official explanation?

Comment: Check [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/43479/89897)

Answer (score 4):

The events you're wondering about didn't happen *between* The Dark World and Ragnarok, they happened *during* The Dark World:

In the final scene before the credits Thor returns to Asgard and decides not to take the throne from Odin. But as he leaves we see it is actually Loki assuming Odin's form:

As for what exactly Loki did, all we really know is that he faked his death, then returned to Asgard posing as a guard sent by Odin to find out where his sons were. Then based on Loki and Odin's comments in Ragnarok, Loki put a spell on him, and brought him to an old age home on Earth.

Answer (score 0):

Loki somehow banished Odin from Asgard, keeping him on Earth until the events of Thor Ragnarok. By doing this, he was able to disguise him as the Allfather without any suspicion on him